# Trouble installing scipy despite having python2.7 and numpy installed already

Tags: python, scipy

I'm having trouble installing scipy via the binaries provided at http://sourceforge.net/projects/scipy/files/scipy/

Double clicking on the mpkg file after mounting the dmg installer gives the following error:
"scipy 0.13.0 can't be installed on this disk. scipy requires System Python 2.7 to install"

However, I already have python 2.7 and numpy installed. The python 2.7 came default with OSX Lion, so I assume it is System Python. With other python modules, one normally can download the binary then run
python setup.py install

Is there a way to cd through the mpkg file and locate a setup.py? Any advice install via this dmg installer?

I know there are other ways to manage python modules, like port and brew. However, I already installed a bunch of packages through setup.py, and I couldn't figure out how to get port to recognize those packages (for example, it will try to reinstall python and numpy via port)

Thanks!

Comment: First, MacPorts can't install packages for your system Python; it builds a whole separate Python 2.7 installation and installs packages for that. And having two 2.7 installations at a time will lead to confusion.

Comment: Meanwhile, I had no problem installing SciPy from source, via `pip` for Lion's system Python 2.7. You will need to install a fortran compiler (e.g., with brew) and you may need to upgrade NumPy, but other than that, it just works. See [here](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/02/installing-scipy-etc-with-apples-python.html) for details.

Comment: The "System Python" the installer requires is most likely the version of Python you can get from http://python.org/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You've got a few misconceptions here.

> With other python modules, one normally can download the binary then run python setup.py install

No, that's what you do with *source* packages.

> Is there a way to cd through the mpkg file and locate a setup.py?

No. What's inside an mpkg are pkg files. Which are filled with xar archives filled with cpio archives. Inside there is the *built* version of SciPy—that is, the files that setup.py would have copied to your site-packages if you'd run it—not the source package.

But you can download the source package yourself.

Or, better, let `pip` (or `easy_install`, but `pip` is better) download and run the setup.py for you.

> Any advice install via this dmg installer?

If it won't work, my advice would be to not use it, and instead install with `pip`.

[This blog post](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/02/installing-scipy-etc-with-apples-python.html) explains it, but I'll give you the details relevant to you below.

> I know there are other ways to manage python modules, like port and brew. However, I already installed a bunch of packages through setup.py, and I couldn't figure out how to get port to recognize those packages.

You can't. MacPorts will not touch your system Python; it builds its own separate Python 2.7, with a completely independent site-packages directory and everything else. You would have to reinstall everything for this second Python 2.7. And deal with the confusion of having two Python 2.7 installations on the same machine.

Don't do that unless you absolutely have to.

In fact, if you want to use Homebrew for *anything* (and you do, see below), uninstall MacPorts, unless you really need it for something.

---

So, here are the steps:

- Uninstall MacPorts.
- I assume you already have Xcode and its Command Line Tools.
- I assume you already have Homebrew.
- Install a Fortran compiler with `brew install gfortran`.
- Lion's Python 2.7 comes with `easy_install`, but not `pip`. So `sudo easy_install pip` to fix that. While you're at it, I'd suggest `sudo easy_install readline`, because you'll want that for ipython, and it won't work right with pip.
- Apple's pre-installed NumPy has to be upgraded, and rebuilt with Fortran support, to make SciPy work. Fix that with `sudo pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall numpy`.
- If you want ipython, pandas, etc. `sudo pip install` each of them as well.

---

In case you're considering upgrading soon, the exact same steps worked for me with OS X 10.9.0, except for some extra work to get the Xcode 5 command line tools set up.

Comment: Same problem: I have Python 2.7, want to re-install scipy from the .mpkg. It says that I don't have System Python 2.7, which is wrong. I do't want to install/use pip nor brew. There should be a simpler way. I tried a complete manual install (0.14.0) with: sudo python setup.py install, but it stopped near the end with a link error ("symbol(s) not found for architecture i386", though I had done export FARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" before.

Comment: @EricH.: If you have a specific problem, create a new question, don't comment on an answer to a question from over a year ago that's for a different OS X, Xcode, and SciPy than you're using and for a user who didn't do things in the same order you did.

Comment: @EricH.: Meanwhile, given that the last installer package for 0.14 came out before OS X 10.10 was even a developer preview, and 10.10 organizes its Python differently than 10.8 (not sure about 10.9) it's not that surprising that it won't recognize your system Python. The initial 10.6 packages didn't work on 10.7 until they were fixed. Maybe try the 0.15b1 package (which came out last week) to see if it works differently.

Comment: @EricH.: Finally, "I don't want to install/use pip"… Why? It's [the official, recommended way to install third-party packages](https://python-packaging-user-guide.readthedocs.org/en/latest/current.html). If you're not going to use it, you have to do everything it does yourself. In this case, that includes making sure your NumPy and SciPy are in sync; since it sounds like you stayed with Apple's pre-installed NumPy, you haven't done that, so things aren't going to work. And you also haven't installed a Fortran compiler; you don't _have_ to use brew for that, but you have to do it _somehow_.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Mavericks and XCode 5, then you'll have to install Command Line Tools manually from the Apple Developer Site. I found [this helpful post](http://discuss.binaryage.com/t/aesepsis-1-4-1-issue-with-update-installing-xcode-command-line-tools/2013)